# How to package Visual Studio extensions into a Nuget package

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, vsix

I would like to create a Visual Studio Nuget package for work. I also want to develop a Visual Studio extension to allow right-click deploy functionality for me and my co-workers. My question is: can I accomplish both of my requirements using the Nuget package alone, or do I have to develop a Nuget package and extension separately? If I have to do them separately, how can I roll the extension into the Nuget package so it can all be delivered together?

Comment: You could probably make use of the [init.ps1/install.ps1](https://everydaylifein.net/netframework/running-powershell-scripts-during-nuget-package-installation-and-removal.html) files to do this. My gripe with this approach would be that when I install a NuGet package, I don't expect Visual Studio to change; only my solution/project changes.

Comment: You can install NuGet packages from your extension using the Nuget API

Comment: Kenneth, that's a really good point about not wanting to changing the behavior of Visual Studio with a Nuget package. I think I need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: ErikEJ, do you have any links on that by any chance?